# Android progressbar with runnable interface

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a code like the below:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
     android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**BasicViews2Activity.java**

```
public class BasicViews2Activity extends Activity 
{     
  static int progress;     
  ProgressBar progressBar;     
  int progressStatus = 0;     
  Handler handler = new Handler();

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */     
  @Override     
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                 
    progress = 0; 
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    //---do some work in background thread--        
    new Thread(new Runnable()        
    {             
      public void run()            
      {                 
        //---do some work here--  
        while (progressStatus < 10)              
        {  
          progressStatus = doSomeWork();   
        }
        //---hides the progress bar---
        handler.post(new Runnable()         
        { 
          public void run()                      
          {  
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);                      
          }                   
        });             
      }

      //---do some long running work here--            
      private int doSomeWork()             
      {                 
        try {    
          Thread.sleep(500);   
        } catch (InterruptedException e)                 
        {                     
          e.printStackTrace();   
        }                 
        return ++progress;             
      }         
    }).start();     
  } 
}
```

Why did we use two runnable objects inside the thread class to cancel the progressbar? Couldn't we do it inside the first runnable obj – just after while loop, without another object?

Answer (score 0):

The asyncTask class can be used easily with progressbars. AS they have an onPreexecute and onPostexecute with which we can update the ui thread from the background activity.

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("waiting 5 minutes..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
    return null;
    }
}
```

Then write an async task to update progress..

```
private class DownloadZipFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Copy you logic to calculate progress and call
        publishProgress("" + progress);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
```

Hope this makes your code easier...

Answer (score 0):

@shaon007 sorry for late post, Yes you can do it with single `runnable` class

Like below

create your xml just the way you have created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
     android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Keep `visibility` option `invisible` for the start

Then in your mainActivity you have to do three things those are

1) Create `Handler` object 
2) Create anonymous `runnable` class 
3) Call `run()` method from `runnable` with setting your `progressbar` visibility

As follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int checkCount = 5000;  // counter for progressbar visibility
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        handler = new Handler();  // handler object

        // runnable class 
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checkCount -= 1000;
                if(checkCount > 0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
                }
                else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Progress bar invisible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Or your other work                    
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);  // will start run() method after 1 second
    }
}
```

And your done